# Detect and Shorting long url text in php

Tags: php, html

I have long Text containg som html urls inside it from database .

im fetching it like that :

```
  echo html_entity_decode($text);
```

and $text is like that in database:

```
    $text = "this is my best <a href='http://www.website.com/andsoooooooooooom_biiiiiiiiiiiiiiiig_characters_heeeeeeeeere'>http://www.website.com/andsoooooooooooom_biiiiiiiiiiiiiiiig_characters_heeeeeeeeere</a> and some text here";
```

it echoes this :

> this is my best http://www.website.com/andsoooooooooooom_biiiiiiiiiiiiiiiig_characters_heeeeeeeeere and some text here

But i want it display shorted text of the url and the href link is same like that :

> > this is my best http://www.website.com/andsoooooo... and some text here

How do i detect how long is it the link text  and then short it automatically when fetching from database BUT the real link stayed as it is in `href` tag  . thanks so much

**EDIT** im not looking to short the `$text` im looking to short the link inside the $text

Answer (score 1):

Use [`substr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php):

```
$text = "this is my best <a href='http://www.website.com/andsoooooooooooom_biiiiiiiiiiiiiiiig_characters_heeeeeeeeere'>http://www.website.com/andsoooooooooooom_biiiiiiiiiiiiiiiig_characters_heeeeeeeeere</a>";

// Gets the whole tag
// e.g.,   "<a href="...">Text</a>"
$linkTag = getTagFromYourUglyAssString($text, "a"); 

// Gets the tag's text value
// e.g.,   "Text"
$linkTagTextOnly = getTagTextFromYourUglyAssString($text, "a");

// Replace $linkTag with $linkTagTextOnly, whichever string you prefer ot shorten
$shortenedText = substr($linkTagTextOnly,0,10).'...';

echo $shortenedText;

function getTagFromYourUglyAssString($string, $tagname) {
    $pattern = "/<$tagname ?.*>.*<\/$tagname>/";
    preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);
    return array_merge($matches);
}

function getTagTextFromYourUglyAssString($string, $tagname) {
    $pattern = "/<$tagname ?.*>(.*)<\/$tagname>/";
    preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);
    return $matches[1];
}
```

**EDIT**: Actually, I think this is what you want:

```
$text = "this is my best <a href='http://www.website.com/andsoooooooooooom_biiiiiiiiiiiiiiiig_characters_heeeeeeeeere'>http://www.website.com/andsoooooooooooom_biiiiiiiiiiiiiiiig_characters_heeeeeeeeere</a>";

$shortenedLink = replaceTagTextFromYourUglyAssString($text, "a");

echo $shortenedLink;
// Should give: 
//   <a href="$text = "this is my best <a href='http://www.website.com/andsoooooooooooom_biiiiiiiiiiiiiiiig_characters_heeeeeeeeere">
//       http://www.website.com/andsoooooooooooom_biiiiiiiiiiiiiiiig_chara...
//   </a>

function replaceTagTextFromYourUglyAssString($string, $tagname) {
    $pattern = "/(<$tagname ?.*>)(.*)(<\/$tagname>)/";
    preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);

    if (count($matches) > 0) {
        return $matches[0].substr($matches[1],0,10).'...'.$matches[2];
    } else {
        // do something else, 'cos no match found
    }
}
```

Comment: how to detect it first

Comment: Detect it...? What do you mean?

Comment: detect text of a link how long then short it . AND in your example it will short the whole text not the link only

Comment: I want short only the link text NOT the whole $text . how you done is simple and i know it

Comment: @ScooterDaraf If it's so easy, perhaps consider using Google to solve that problem then. I've updated the question with how I think it should be done.

Comment: @ScooterDaraf Question is updated. If you just want the text between the link updated, I'll do an edit for that now.

Comment: im getting this error sir : `substr() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in`

Comment: now with this update , im not getting the text after the a link

Comment: Missing argument 2 for replaceTagTextFromYourUglyAssString()

Comment: @ScooterDaraf That's a very simple error to fix. Read the error message a couple times and try guess what it means. I've fixed the code in the example for that.

Comment: added "a" argument now the error is `Undefined offset: 2`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120112/discussion-between-nick-bull-and-scooter-daraf).